# Multiline comment on merge request with GitLab REST API

Tags: json, gitlab, gitlab-api, merge-request

I'm trying to post a comment that spans multiple lines of the changes of a merge request on gitlab, using the gitlab REST API. So far I've managed to make the comment spanning multiple lines using the following JSON body:

```json
{
  "position": {
    "base_sha": "4af5230bd8894e9e56a5343537fd0f5dd1d3341b",
    "start_sha": "4af5230bd8894e9e56a5343537fd0f5dd1d3341b",
    "head_sha": "7e5df9ede4766b0c33509881055d00be94debdae",
    "new_path": "test.php",
    "old_path": "test.php",
    "position_type": "text",
    "new_line": 20,
    "line_range": {
      "start": {
        "line_code": "63b0bac63e6a8d4a13fe35e04eac455258e9500b_18_18",
        "type": "new"
      },
      "end": {
        "line_code": "63b0bac63e6a8d4a13fe35e04eac455258e9500b_18_20",
        "type": "new"
      }
    },
    "ignore_whitespace_change": false
  },
  "body": "test comment body"
}
```

This comment, unlike the comments i can make via the website, doesn't have the "Comment on lines +28 to +30" text above it.

The comment without the text:

[image: Comment without text]

The comment with the text:

[image: Comment with text]

Is it possible to get the text above it using the GitLab REST API? I've tried browsing the GitLab REST API documentation to find a solution, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute called "`new_line`" in the `start` and `end` sections of `line_range`

Assuming the comments are for line 28 to 30 as you mentioned in your screenshot

```
{
    "position": {
        "base_sha": "4af5230bd8894e9e56a5343537fd0f5dd1d3341b",
        "start_sha": "4af5230bd8894e9e56a5343537fd0f5dd1d3341b",
        "head_sha": "7e5df9ede4766b0c33509881055d00be94debdae",
        "new_path": "test.php",
        "old_path": "test.php",
        "position_type": "text",
        "new_line": 20,
        "line_range": {
            "start": {
                "line_code": "63b0bac63e6a8d4a13fe35e04eac455258e9500b_18_18",
                "type": "new",
                "new_line": 28
            },
            "end": {
                "line_code": "63b0bac63e6a8d4a13fe35e04eac455258e9500b_18_20",
                "type": "new",
                "new_line": 30
            }
        },
        "ignore_whitespace_change": false
    },
    "body": "test comment body"
}
```

Let me know if this works for you and if it does then please accept the answer, so that others can benefit.

Comment: Adding the new_line part results in the error:
400 Bad request - Note {:position=>[\"must be a valid json schema\"]}